# No Immediate Successor? No Largest Element?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I am reading through the proof of the following theorem in Munkres' topology:

> Every well-ordered set $X$ is normal in the order topology.

Here is a troubling quote from Munkres'

> We assert that every interval of the form $(x,y]$ is open in $X$: If $X$ has a largest element and $y$ is that element, then $(x,y]$ is just a basis element about $y$. If $y$ is not the largest element of $X$, then $(x,y]$ equals the open set $(x,y')$, where $y'$ is the immediate successor of $y$.

First, what if $y$ isn't the largest element; will $(x,y]$ still be open? Secondly, what if $y$ has no immediate successor? I don't quite follow Munkres' reasoning.

Comment: Try playing with an example. Can you come up with an interval in $\Bbb N$ which can be written as $(0,n]$ and $(0,k)$?

Comment: y must have an immediate successor because X is a well ordered set.

Comment: Every order topology is normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every element $s$ in a well-ordered set has an immediate successor, except possibly the greatest element.

Proof: consider the set $X$ of elements $t$ such that $t>s$. What does the well-order tell you about $X$?

Answer (score 4):

Assume $y$ is not the greatest element in $X$.

$X$ is a well ordered set.  (Which the reals and the rationals are not which makes *everything* about Munkres' argument counterintuitive.  That is to say, the "usual" meaning of "<" is not a well-ordered one.)

So $S = \{s \in X|s > y\}$ will have a least element.  Call it $y'$.

Then we have $v < y' \iff v \le y$ (which would *never* be the case if $X$ were the real numbers under the "usual" order.)

So $(x, y] = \{v \in X| x < v \le y\} = \{v \in X|x < v < y'\} = (x,y')$ which is an open set.

If $y$ *is* the greatest element in $S$. Then $(x,y] = \{v\in X| v > x\}=(x,\infty)$ [if Munkres uses that notation] and that is a basis open set.

Either way $(x,y]$ is an open set.

.....

This is obviously very different than in the rationals or the reals where there would never be any $y$ and $y'$ where $(x , y] = (x,y')$.  However where $X = \mathbb Z$ then $(x ,y] = \{n| x < n \le y\} = \{n|x < n < y+1\} = (x,y+1)$.

Comment: Probably misleading to say "the reals and the rationals are not." It is not a matter of whether they are or aren't, period; it's a matter of whether they are *with respect to a certain order*. I know you mean "with respect to the standard order," but some readers might not. The well-ordering theorem says both sets *can* be well-ordered, of course.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  My point was that well-ordering and out common notation of (x,y] = (x,y') is (to me at least, utterly counter-intuitive).

Answer (score 2):

If $y$ isn't the largest element, then it will have an immediate successor. If $y$ has an immediate successor, then it isn't the largest element. In either case, you can show that $(x, y]$ is open. This covers all possibilities.